# What influences the finishing taste in your beer?

Tags: all-grain, flavor

The beers that I tend to really like have that pleasant finishing taste before the after taste.  What influences a beer's finish?

I'd like to take some styles that I like that leave a little bit to desire and give it that last little oomph and complexity.

If this is subjective to the beer style then I'd like to narrow it down to a Witbier.  Some Wit's I've tasted were okay but needed that wheat taste at the finish to really shine.

Am I on the right track in my thinking that it can be pinpointed that you can do x to add flavor to the finish?

Answer (score 3):

A lot of times, you can add something to the secondary fermentation for a finishing taste.  For instance, if you added cocoa nibs to secondary, you'd end up with chocolate on the finish.  If you added a fruity hop (like Galaxy) to secondary, you'd pick up on melon or passion fruit on the finish.  I've seen folks cold brew coffee and add that for a coffee finish.  Remember, a little of something can go a long way.

Comment: What about the distinct finishing flavors of some Oktoberfest or Witbiers where you can taste the grain but then there are other Oktoberfests and Witbiers that do not have that?

Comment: Oktoberfest beers are notoriously lightly hopped.  If you look at most Oktoberfest recipes, they have bittering hops (typically low AA% German hops) and none for flavor or aroma.  This will counter the sweetness of the wort while allowing the drinker to taste the malt.  You also find this in some stouts and porters.